# Understanding and optimizing SceneKit draw calls

Tags: macos, scenekit

I'm using SceneKit to draw 'thick lines' with rounded end caps.
I found out that the fastest way to do so is drawing them in 3 parts: one rectangular body and two circular end caps.
I've a problem (or misunderstanding) with the number of draw calls SceneKit uses to draw these lines.

I've the following scene graph created:

```
scene's root node -> image node -> sr node -> level node -> line node
```

Each line node contains 3 nodes for the 3 parts. The other nodes are there to support the rest of the data model. All geometries have the same material.

Drawing 5 lines takes 11 draw calls. The strange thing is that when I either omit the body, or omit both endcaps, it only takes 2 draw calls. Why doesn't drawing both body and end caps take 3 or 4 draw calls?
The problem becomes worse when drawing 3076 lines, taking 6.15k draw calls when completely drawn, while only taking 10 draw calls for just the body or end caps.

I tried to make a test setup to find the problem, which looks like this:

```
SCNNode *imageNode=[SCNNode node];
imageNode.name=@"image";
[self.sceneView.scene.rootNode addChildNode:imageNode];

SCNNode *srNode=[SCNNode node];
srNode.name=@"sr";
[imageNode addChildNode:srNode];
SCNNode *levelNode=[SCNNode node];

levelNode.name=@"level";
[srNode addChildNode:levelNode];

NSBezierPath *path1=[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 1, 1)];
NSBezierPath *path2=[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 1, 2)];
SCNShape *shape1=[SCNShape shapeWithPath:path1 extrusionDepth:0];
shape1.name=@"cap shape";
SCNShape *shape2=[SCNShape shapeWithPath:path2 extrusionDepth:0];
shape2.name=@"body shape";

for (NSUInteger i=0; i<5; i+=1) {
    SCNNode *node=[SCNNode node];
    node.name=@"line";

    SCNNode *node1=[SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:shape1];
    node1.name=@"cap";
    node1.position=SCNVector3Make(rand()/(float)RAND_MAX*10, rand()/(float)RAND_MAX*10, 0);

    SCNNode *node2=[SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:shape2];
    node2.name=@"body";
    node2.position=SCNVector3Make(rand()/(float)RAND_MAX*10, rand()/(float)RAND_MAX*10, 0);
    node2.scale=SCNVector3Make(2, 6, 1);
    [node addChildNode:node1];
    [node addChildNode:node2];

    node1=[node1 copy];
    node1.position=SCNVector3Make(rand()/(float)RAND_MAX*10, rand()/(float)RAND_MAX*10, 0);
    [node addChildNode:node1];

    [levelNode addChildNode:node];
}
```

Which first creates the basic part of the graph. Then creates two geometries to represent the body and endcaps and then constructs a number of line nodes.

I noticed that if all (both) geometries share *the exact same* material, the draw call count is indeed 6.15k. If shape2 has a `copy` of shape1's material. The draw call count is the more expected 12.

How can I find out why using the same material takes so many draw calls? 
The documentation clearly states that materials are intended to be re-used for different geometries.

Comment: Not sure that it addresses this specific question, but this 2017 WWDC talk has some useful commentary on draw call count in general: https://asciiwwdc.com/2017/sessions/605